# What is the correct way of mentioning project experience in CV?

Tags: resume, work-experience

We are 3 engineers and one product manager working in the project.
What I want to mention is that as an engineer, I am one of the main people in the development of that project.
What is the correct way of mentioning it in CV?

Is it OK to write:

```
Highly participating in the development of X
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If I asked you "so what did you do when you worked on x" what would you say?  For example, in the world of software, on a lot of project I'm a software architect but we don't have an actual "leader" per se.  So on my  CV it says "software architect and domain expert in x y z on project _" or something to that effect.  Maintain an active and specific voice throughout.

Answer (score 1):

You could say "Key contributor to the design, development, testing and implementation of ....." then go on to specify exactly what tasks you were responsible for.

Comment: probably better to be more specific. In many cases when someone claims to handle all parts of implementation of a project I tend to feel either the project is smaller than they presented it to be, or they are "fudging" reality. (All developers can claim all the mentioned pieces, but did they actually design large portions of the project, or did they design particular functionality?) Specifics sell it as more plausible.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on if you want to place the emphasis on the title and/or the actual involvement that you have had in the project.

If you are the key/lead engineer, then the title will suggest that you have a main role in the development of that project.

If it is a team and different people had different roles, then you should specify your contribution under the responsibilities/achievements/outcomes of the project.

Writing that you participated to a high degree as you proposed, will only like to draw the same questions that you can already answer by providing better details in the cv.

Comment: The more specific you can be (in a concise way) the better. Simply put when you're going out of your way to mention a project in your CV you want to sell your role in it. Did you lead the project level design? or did you flesh out the design of functionality? What were your specific contributions on the project? I need to know what you did on the project to get a feeling for why it's relevant. (you don't need to list every little detail, stuff like "I setup the payment processor to utilize a third party vendor for facilitating credit card transactions" etc.)